# Convert in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list like -

```
body = ['"name","number"', '"Dudh & Pani Dudh & Pani Dudh Wala","+91 70148 05126"', '"Deepanshu Paymate","+91 72082 94015"']

df = pd.DataFrame(body)
print(df)
```

Output is -

```
                                                   0
0                                    "name","number"
1  "Dudh & Pani Dudh & Pani Dudh Wala","+91 70148...
2              "Deepanshu Paymate","+91 72082 94015"
```

But I want two columns the first one will be named and second will be number.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with `split` with all data without first value of list and for columns split first value of `list`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x .split(',') for x in body[1:]], columns=body[0].split(','))
print(df)
                                "name"           "number"
0  "Dudh & Pani Dudh & Pani Dudh Wala"  "+91 70148 05126"
1                  "Deepanshu Paymate"  "+91 72082 94015"
```

If want strip `""`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[y.strip('"') for y in x.split(',')] for x in body[1:]], 
                    columns=[y.strip('"') for y in body[0].split(',')])
print(df)
                                name           number
0  Dudh & Pani Dudh & Pani Dudh Wala  +91 70148 05126
1                  Deepanshu Paymate  +91 72082 94015
```

Another idea with `replace`:

```
body = [x.replace("'","").replace('"','') for x in body]
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in body[1:]], columns=body[0].split(','))
print(df)

                                name           number
0  Dudh & Pani Dudh & Pani Dudh Wala  +91 70148 05126
1                  Deepanshu Paymate  +91 72082 94015
```

Answer (score 1):

From your list of strings we make (by list comprehension) a list of
lists of pairs [name, number], and from this new list we create your
dataframe:

```
 In[16]: new_body = [element.split(",")  for element in body]
 In[17]: df = pd.DataFrame(new_body)

 In[18]: df
 Out[18]:
                                      0                  1
 0                               "name"           "number"
 1  "Dudh & Pani Dudh & Pani Dudh Wala"  "+91 70148 05126"
 2                  "Deepanshu Paymate"  "+91 72082 94015"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
body = ['"name","number"', '"Dudh & Pani Dudh & Pani Dudh Wala","+91 70148 05126"', '"Deepanshu Paymate","+91 72082 94015"']
```

use

```
body = [["name","number"], ["Dudh & Pani Dudh & Pani Dudh Wala","+91 70148 05126"], ["Deepanshu Paymate","+91 72082 94015"]]
```

i. e. instead of surrounding pairs with apostrophes: `'...'`, surround them with square brackets: `[...]`.

Then the dataframe created with `df = pd.DataFrame(body)` will be

> ```
>                                    0                1
> 0                               name           number
> 1  Dudh & Pani Dudh & Pani Dudh Wala  +91 70148 05126
> 2                  Deepanshu Paymate  +91 72082 94015
> ```

Answer (score -1):

I found this way -

```
body = ['"name","number"', '"Dudh & Pani Dudh & Pani Dudh Wala","+91 70148 05126"', '"Deepanshu Paymate","+91 72082 94015"']

data = pd.DataFrame(body)

# new data frame with split value columns 
data = data[0].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True) 

new_header = data.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
data = data[1:] #take the data less the header row
data.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header

print(data)
```

Output is -

```
0                               "name"           "number"
1  "Dudh & Pani Dudh & Pani Dudh Wala"  "+91 70148 05126"
2                  "Deepanshu Paymate"  "+91 72082 94015"
```